# Change variable script

Tags: javascript, jquery

i ma using this code to disable ValidUntil field when ExpirationTime has a valued, the problem this only work when i made a change but not when i edit the record, is there any way to modify this code for always disable Validuntil  if Expirationtime has a value?

```
$('#x_ExpirationTime').on('change', function() {
if(this.value.length > 0)
$('#x_ValidUntil').attr('disabled','disabled');
else
$('#x_ValidUntil').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "edit the record"?

Comment: Can you kindly share more code. The HTML if you can and let us know where you are setting the above function. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute the code inside the event without the `change` action to make it work by itself. You have a few options:

1. Force the event execution:

   ```
   $('#x_ExpirationTime').on('change', function() { }).change();
   ```

   Add `change()` at end of the event binding to execute it after the page initialization. It will work as if user has changed it;
2. Separate the event body in a function:

   ```
   function checkValue() {
       let $input = $('#x_ValidUntil');
       if($('#x_ExpirationTime').val().length > 0)    
           $input.attr('disabled','disabled');
       else
           $input.removeAttr('disabled');
   }

   $('#x_ExpirationTime').on('change', checkValue);

   checkValue();
   ```

   The isolated call to `checkValue()` will make the magic.

Both ways will have the same outcome.

Comment: Hello, first thanks, this code is working but in wrong way, is disable when ExpirationTime is null, i need disable when ExpirationTime is not null, how fix this thanks

Comment: Thanks now work you rock, thanks for all help everyvary

Comment: @Ninja you probably have inverted the condition, right? Np, you're welcome!